# Vesak 2561/2017 TODAY Where in western world can traditional & benefical celebrations be aspected?

Tags: veneration

Valued Upasaka, Upasika,

Dear seeker for way to awakening and readers,

**Vesak-Pūjā** *(Birth, Awakening and Paranibbana-Remembering day of the Buddha, (Vesak= Name of the secound month of the luna calender/pi: Visaka; Pūjā = sacrify, veneration.)*

It's the near end of an auspicious period in which most Nikayas cellerbrated Uposatha in timely union. A season in which seldom, even last oppotunities and possibilities that place.

Only some view more days the bigges celebration, now undertaken nearly all over the world (!) - some say it's the fist time and actually so that it is cellebrated in the whole world - and the main and biggest Veneration of our times Buddha, takes place.

1. Where in the western world are such as a real Sangha established and traditional and benefical *Vesak-Pūjās* undertaken by the Ven. Monks where people, young and old, rich or poor, could part-take also in their own county on 10. of May, today?
2. Where in traditional countries are - usually much by serious "western" people from abroad frequented - traditional and benefical *Vesak-Pūjā* taking place.

(Please, if knowing, do not share often usual kermis and trade fairs)

May you rejoice by sharing merits and invitations to such, as well those many able to take part on you futune. Anumodana!

So where to got today evening to make sacrifies to the Buddha? May all take up this possibility today and gain liberating joy with it!

*(Note: This question is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpoes or other wordily gains.)*

Answer (score 1):

For this Vesak, I will be going to the [Mahamevanawa Buddhist Monastery & Buddha Meditation Centre of Greater Toronto](https://www.facebook.com/MahamevnawaToronto/). On this day I, together with 300+ others will be observing 24+ Uposatha Sil. Buddha recommended that the disciples follow additional precepts to the first 5 precepts whenever time permits. These are known as the Uposatha Precepts, or simply the Eight Precepts. They are traditionally observed on the full-moon days (uposatha). This give us the opportunity to practice some of the renunciation that those who follow the Buddha’s teaching to the highest goal of enlightenment give up completely. So when we spend time following these training rules, we can remember that we are imitating these great spiritual beings. It is said that:

> Whatever wealth exists within this sphere— pearls, gems, and beryl, an excellent stone, singi gold or natural mountain gold, and the gold called hataka— those are not worth a sixteenth part of an uposatha complete in the eight factors, just as all the hosts of stars do not match the moon's radiance.  - Visakha Uposatha Sutta (Numerical Discourses, AN 8:43)

On this day I will participate in a special “Pirith Sajgayana” (recitation) that will last till dawn. We normally get together at least once every month to chant Pirith (from 7.00 pm to past midnight usually & covering all of the important suttas) to help turn away all sorrows, (sabba dukkha), ailments, (sabba roga), and all fears ( sabba bhaya).

The Supreme Buddha said, “One who abides in the Dhamma, delights in the Dhamma, meditates on the Dhamma and bears the Dhamma well in mind, does never fall away from the Sublime Dhamma". By reciting Pirith we do all of the above and help invoke the blessings of the Triple Gem for protection.

On this Vesak Day we celebrate three great events. These three great events in the life of the Buddha are - the birth of Prince Sidhartha, the Bodhisatva at the Royal Park of Lumbini, His attainment of the Perfect Enlightenment in his 35th year under the shade of Sri Maha Bodhi at Buddha Gaya, His demise after a noble ministry that lasted 45 years at Kusinara in the Sala Grove, Upavartana that belonged to Royalty of Malla. These 3 events occured on the Vesak Full Moon Poya Day. It is renowned as the most sacred Poya Day in the Buddhist world over.

There is an additional Vesak Poya called "Adhi Vesak Full Moon Poya Day" that occurs once in 3 years, due to the change of planetary movements. Whether it is Wesak or Adhi Wesak, or any other day, the need of the hour is to follow the Message of the Buddha Dhamma. The knowledge of Buddhism is the key to the higher Path.

Mahamevnawa was established by much venerated monk, Ven. Kiribathgoda Gnanananda (VKG). He was not born Buddhist. Baptized as Jude Cabraal, born on 1st July 1961, he was the third child & the first son of the Roman Catholic family. When in University (age 17?) he became a monk. But his higher ordination, his disillusion of a namesake ordination made him opt out to become a Samanera again, since the Vinaya is not given a due prominence. He de-robed, misguided that his search for truth can be achieved as a lay “Upasaka”. Later he became a monk again, portraying his unwavering resolve to achieve his final goal. Today the [Mahamevnawa Buddhist Monastery](http://mahamevnawa.lk/inenglish/), that he formed has several branches in the Western World. Given below is a list of most of them:

[Mahamevnawa Buddhist Monastery Toronto, Canada](http://www.mahamevnawa.ca/photo-gallery.html).  - 11175 Kennedy Road , Markham , Ontario , L6C 1P2 Canada   Tel: (905) 927 7117  E-mail: info@mahamevnawa.ca

[Mahamevnawa Buddhist Nuns' Center and Meditation Center of Halton Hills](http://www.buddhistnuns.ca/). [9148 MAIN STREET SOUTH, ACTON, HALTON HILLS, ONTARIO](http://www.buddhistnuns.ca/index.php/about-us1/photo-gallery), L7J 1X9. Canada.

[Mahamevnawa Buddhist Monastery Edmonton, Canada](http://mahamevnawaedmonton.com/). 13036 SHERBROOKE AVE NW, EDMONTON, AB T5L 4E8.

[Buddha Meditation Centre Saskatoon, Saskatoon, Canada.](http://www.mahamevnawasaskatoon.com/) 602 Stonebridge Common, Saskatoon SK S7T 0M9. Telephone: (306) 374-2840, Email: info@mahamevnawasaskatoon.com

[Buddha Meditation Centre, Winnipeg, Canada.](http://www.mahamevnawawinnipeg.org/) 2610 St Mary’s Road, Winnipeg, MB R2N 4A2

[Mahamevnawa Meditation Monastery, Offenbach, Germany](http://mahamevnawa.lk/worldwide-mahamevnawa-branches/mahamevnawa-buddhist-monastery-germany/)

[Mahamevnawa Monastery, Sydney, Australia](http://mahamevnaaus.org/) 105, Wisemans Ferry Road,
Cattai NSW 2756 Australia. +61 245 728 872

[Mahamevnawa Monastery, Melbourne, Australia](http://mahamevnawa.org.au/) 71 Monbulk Road,
Mount Evelyn, VIC 3796  +61 03 9736 3937

[Mahamevnawa Buddhist Monastery, Adelaide, Australia](http://mahamevnawaadel.org/) 1105, Grand Junction Road,
Hope Valley, SA 5090. +61 08 8364 4879

[Mahamevnawa Monastery,  UK](http://mahamevnawaimc.org/) Dhamma land, Hardings Elms Road
Crays Hill, BILLERICAY, Essex CM11 2UH.  01268 533870.. Web    mahamevnawaimc.org; 
mahamevnawaimc.co.uk;  mahamevnawa.uk;  buddhameditation.uk;  Email  admin@mahamevnawaimc.org

[Mahamevnawa Monastery, New Jersey, United States](http://mahamevnawa.lk/mahamevnawa-buddhist-monasteries-abroad/mahamevnawa-buddhist-meditation-centre-new-jersey/)

[Mahamevnawa Monastery, California, USA](http://www.mahamevnawa.us/about-us/) 9917, Mission Blvd, Jurupa Valley, CA 92509
Phone: 714 884 3894

Mahamevnawa Monastery, Florida, USA. 2714 DOERUN CT, TAMPA, FL 33618
(813) 961-5296

[Mahamevnawa Monastery, Washington D.C., USA](http://mahamevnawadc.org/) 5004 Stone Rd, Rockville, MD 20853, USA

[Mahamevnawa Monastery, Ireland](http://mahamevnawa.ie/)

[Mahamevnawa Monastery, France](http://www.mahamevnawa.fr/) 6 bis Rue Maurice Laisney, 92600 Asnières-sur-Seine.  +33 9 70 99 46 65

Comment: Sadhu, Sadhu, Sadhu. Especially for the extanded teachings and share of own merits. Anumodana! Does Upasaka/-ika also likes to share a contact, link and adress of the monastery, so that those near and far, inspired to paticipate in practice of veneration, undertaking the precsepts and seeing and meeting the monks, could possible ease part-take? Maybe he/she likes to add it in the answer.

Comment: Maybe it's also possible to add "Canada/Toronto" bold at the beginning, so that others could easy find near to their location.

Comment: I gave just one link for now, but will try to give more late in the day. With metta.

Comment: Sadhu. No need to hurry. Those in hurry are depend on taking google, those honoring gifts will take their time to receive. Ohh... facebook is maybe not so good, since not all especially those keeping the eight silas and more constant would maybe no being citizens there and would have a hard to access.

Comment: Access possible without citizens-ship. Just another question, seeing the page (link of monastery: http://www.Mahamevnawa.ca/ ), is it in relation with the Dhammakaya-branch of Thailand?